# How to select specific properties of properties through DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I have the following Entities. First and foremost: the design derived from a legacy DB and it has been semplified here for clarity shake.

[image]

What I would like to do is selecting all the `widgets` along with their `varsSelection` populated (in this very moment `Widget` only contains `PhyVarSelection` instances so we can focus on them) which should have teir `phyVar` hydrated. `Phyvar` must not be populated with its `ewCfgVar` property.

I'm trying to do it by using DQL. I succeeded to select all the widgets and their relative `varsSelection`, but I'm not able to populate their relative `phyVar`. Is that possible? Here is the DQL I'm using:

```
        $sql = <<<EOS
        SELECT wid, partial phyvarsel.{id, phyVar, start}
        FROM Belka\\TsBundle\\Entity\\Widget wid
        LEFT JOIN Belka\\TsBundle\\Entity\\PhyVarSelection phyvarsel WITH wid.id = phyvarsel.widget
        LEFT JOIN Belka\\TsBundle\\Entity\\PhyVar phyvar WITH phyvarsel.phyVar = phyvar.id
EOS;

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($sql);
```

If I dump the result, `Widget` and `varsSelection` are correctly populated, but `PhyVarSelection::phyVar` is set to NULL.

The query DQL it generates is actually correct, and if I query it I get all the `PhyVar`'s properties:

```
die(var_dump($query->getSQL()));
```

It generates:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.title AS title1, a0_."order" AS order2, a0_.span_cols AS span_cols3, a0_.description AS description4, a1_.id AS id5, a1_.start AS start6, a2_.id AS id7, a0_.part_of_section AS part_of_section8, a1_.vartype AS vartype9, a1_.part_of_widget AS part_of_widget10, a1_.phy_var_sel AS phy_var_sel11, a2_.vartype AS vartype12, a2_.part_of_phy_meter AS part_of_phy_meter13, a2_.varname AS varname14, a2_.id_device AS id_device15 FROM app_t.widget a0_ LEFT JOIN app_t.var_selection a1_ ON (a0_.id = a1_.part_of_widget) AND a1_.vartype IN ('phy') LEFT JOIN app_t.variable a2_ ON (a1_.phy_var_sel = a2_.id) AND a2_.vartype IN ('phy');
```

I don't paste here the `Entities`' code but if you need it let me know with a comment below and I will update the question.

**Update**

I've also tried the following:

```
        $sql2 = <<<EOS
        SELECT phyvarsel, phyvar
        FROM Belka\\TsBundle\\Entity\\PhyVarSelection phyvarsel
        LEFT JOIN Belka\\TsBundle\\Entity\\PhyVar phyvar
        WHERE phyvarsel.id = :phyvarselid
EOS;


        $query2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($sql2);
        $query2->setParameter('phyvarselid', '0');
        $query2->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);
        $varSel = $query2->getResult();
```

again, in this case I get `PhyVarSelection` but its attribute `phyVar` is still set to NULL.